# Asp.Net client certificate authentication problem after chrome update 83.0.4103.61

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my website, I use client certificate authentication. But when update chrome I have problem with authenticate. In my code when a user enters I check **Request.ClientCertificate.Count > 0** condition. Before the update, this get count of the certificate, but after update **Request.ClientCertificate.Count** code return zero. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, we found the problem. We update our Windows server then the problem solved.